# Serialize bits from input/output pin with VHDL

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

The code below reads 40 bits of data sent in serial from a DHT-11 temperature/humidity sensor and 
stores the data in a 5 byte array of RAM.

The code is:

```
// Return values:

// DHTLIB_OK              0 => OK
// DHTLIB_ERROR_CHECKSUM -1 => Checksum error
// DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT  -2 => Timeout


int read(int pin)
{

    uint8_t bits[5]; // BUFFER TO RECEIVE
    uint8_t cnt = 7; // bit counter 0..7
    uint8_t idx = 0; // buffer index

    // EMPTY BUFFER
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) bits[i] = 0;

    // REQUEST SAMPLE
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);    // set pin for output    
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);  // write '0'
    delay(18);               // delay 18ms
    digitalWrite(pin, HIGH); // write '1'
    delayMicroseconds(40);   // delay 40 microseconds

    pinMode(pin, INPUT);     // set pin for input

    // ACKNOWLEDGE or TIMEOUT
    unsigned int loopCnt = 10000; 
    while(digitalRead(pin) == LOW)
        if (loopCnt-- == 0) return DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT;

    loopCnt = 10000;
    while(digitalRead(pin) == HIGH)
        if (loopCnt-- == 0) return DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT;

    // READ OUTPUT - 40 BITS => 5 BYTES or TIMEOUT
    for (int i=0; i<40; i++)
    {
        loopCnt = 10000;
        while(digitalRead(pin) == LOW)
            if (loopCnt-- == 0) return DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT;

        unsigned long t = micros();  // this function returns the timestamp in microseconds

        loopCnt = 10000;
        while(digitalRead(pin) == HIGH)
            if (loopCnt-- == 0) return DHTLIB_ERROR_TIMEOUT;

        if ((micros() - t) > 40) bits[idx] |= (1 << cnt);
        if (cnt == 0)   // next byte?
        {
            cnt = 7;    // restart at MSB
            idx++;      // next byte!
        }
        else cnt--;
    }

    // WRITE TO RIGHT VARS
              // as bits[1] and bits[3] are allways zero they are omitted in formulas.
    humidity    = bits[0]; 
    temperature = bits[2]; 

    uint8_t sum = bits[0] + bits[2];  

    if (bits[4] != sum) return DHTLIB_ERROR_CHECKSUM;
    return DHTLIB_OK;
}
```

I'm beginning to FPGA developing, but I can't catch some concepts of VHDL, such as poling 
a pin of a FPGA. 
For testing, I'm using a Xilinx Spartan 3E with a clock of 50 MHz.

The C function that returns an int (Ok, checksum error, or timeout error).

The equivalent VHDL code doesn't do that, of course, but instead, stores the int in a variable.

Can you please, help me convert the code above to VHDL?

Answer (score 4):

If you're struggling to catch the VHDL concepts, don't start with that kind of project!

Start smaller.

First, flash an LED at 1Hz.  Now build a simulation for the same code.  Normally, you'd build the simulation first, but I know that most people *really* want to see some hardware working ASAP!

Now wire up a pushbutton switch to the FPGA and use it to stop and start the LED flashing.  Don't forget to debounce it.  Simulate first, then demonstrate in hardware.

Once you've done those two tasks you will have some more idea about VHDL, and can ask smaller questions about the task you want to complete, rather than just dumping a load of C code and asking for it to be converted into VHDL.

Comment: I've starting done what you said. The code I've dumped is for measuring pulse duration (variable duty cyle). I'm trying to simulate this with a push button.  So I need to do the following: 1) Press a button an reset a counter. 2) While the button still pressed, increment the counter. 3) When the button is released, display the counter in a row of 8 Leds. Can you please point me an example that implements this? This is not a question of laziness. I have experience in hardware and microcontroller programming, and now, with VHDL, I feel like I back in time 10 years.

Comment: Have you done the first two tasks (flashing an LED, and then starting and stopping it with a debounced switch?)?  If so please raise a new question.  If not, please do that first...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Martin Thompson answer, but I would like to add that:

VHDL is not a computer language like "C" or "java". You cannot *convert* sequential code to hardware description language.

Of course, you can describe a piece of hardware that does the same function than the posted code. But in any case it won't be "VHDL code running on the FPGA".

If you want to go for HLD, I suggest that you start by understanding the fundamentals behind HDL coding. Very nice and free resources are available on the WEB. Major FPGA manufacturers offer online course for free on their websites. This is a good starting point.

Before you even try to build something, I suggest that you try to forget anything you know about computer language and start form scratch by thinking "hardware". E.G.: everything I describe runs in parallel. etc...

Comment: Ths idea is exactly what you said: a piece of hardware (in this case VHDL code) that does the same function as the posted code. When I learned programming languages, my first difficulty was learn the FIRST language. After that, the rest was intuitive. P.S.: Hardware is not a issue for me. I have many years of hardware and microcontroller experience. The problem is leverage VHDL with my previous knowledge.